# Docker: google/docker-registry container usage

Tags: docker, google-cloud-storage, docker-registry

Does the google/docker-registry container exist solely to push/pull images from Google Cloud Storage? I am currently following their [instructions](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/google/docker-registry/) on Git and have the docker-registry container running, but can't seem to pull from my bucket.

I started it with:

```
sudo docker run -d -e GCS_BUCKET=mybucket -p 5000:5000 google/docker-registry
```

I have a .tar Docker image stored in Cloud Storage, at mybucket/imagename.tar. However, when I execute:

```
sudo docker pull localhost:5000/imagename.tar
```

It results in:

2014/07/10 19:15:50 HTTP code: 404

Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You need to `docker push` to the registy instead of copying your image tar manually.

From where you image is:

```
docker run -ti --name gcloud-config google/cloud-sdk \
  gcloud auth login
docker run -ti --volumes-from gcloud-config google/cloud-sdk \
  gcloud config set project <project>
docker run -d -e GCS_BUCKET=bucketname -p 5000:5000 \
  --volumes-from gcloud-config google/docker-registry
docker tag imagename localhost:5000/imagename
docker push localhost:5000/imagename
```

Then from the place you want to run the image from (ex: GCE):

```
docker run -d -e GCS_BUCKET=bucketname -p 5000:5000 google/docker-registry
docker run localhost:5000/imagename
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. After following those commands exactly, it produced the following error after the "docker push localhost:5000/imagename" command:

Comment: docker@boot2docker:~$ docker push localhost:5000/imagename
2014/07/15 22:17:07 Error: Invalid Registry endpoint: Get http://localhost:5000/
v1/_ping: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5000: connection refused

Comment: As a note, after each of the first 3 "docker run" commands, I type "exit" to get out of the container and run the next one. Let me know if there is another way I should be doing this.

Comment: `docker ps -a` should give you more info about the exit status of `google/docker-registry`

Comment: docker@boot2docker:~$ docker ps -a
a655b6c18ddb        google/docker-registry:latest   /bin/sh -c 'cd /dock   6 min
utes ago       Exited (3) 6 seconds ago                          jolly_curie

e2eab59f6be8        google/cloud-sdk:latest         /bin/sh -c bash        12 mi
nutes ago      Exited (0) 11 minutes ago                         grave_turing

4ff82430b78a        google/cloud-sdk:latest         /bin/sh -c bash        16 mi
nutes ago      Exited (130) 12 minutes ago                       gcloud-config

Comment: When I use docker ps -a, all the containers say "Exited". Is this not supposed to be the case? I am still getting the aforementioned error.

Comment: If it says 'Exited' w/ a code != 0, it means there was an error. Use `docker logs <container-id>` to get the logs and more info.

Comment: Solved. I had not created the bucket before executing this command, it results in an error otherwise.

Comment: did the error message container enough information for you to figure this out? if not, please consider filing an issue on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/docker-registry/issues

Answer (score 0):

When using the google/docker-registry it is preconfigured to use the google buckets.

It should work for any storage (if configuration is overriden), but it's purpose is to be used with the google infrastructure.

The tar file of an exported image should be used when there is no docker registry to manually move images between docker hosts.

You should not upload tar files to the bucket.

To upload images, you should push to the docker-registry container, it will the save the image in the bucket.

The google cloud compute instance that is running the docker registry container must be configured to have write/read access to the bucket.